# Как считать данные из файла в Slim

Tags: php, slim

Как в фреймворке Slim считать содержимое файла и вывести это? Например, код ниже работает в обычном PHP приложении:

```
<?php
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\s1\vendor\me.json'), true);
print data["data"][0]["id"];
```

Но, если я в Slim я пишу код нижеследующий код, то ничего не выходит:

```
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app->get('/test/', function(Request $reg, Response $res, $args = []){
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\s1\vendor\me.json'), true);
return $res->$data["data"][0]["id"];
});
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно вывести только, `$data["data"][0]["id"]`, то попробуйте

```
$res->getBody()->write($data["data"][0]["id"]); 
return $res;
```